# initState method giving the same value in loop state

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two `StateFul` widget one contains ListView.builder
and second contains text Widget. Now I am putting the second `StateFul` as item in in listview.builder like following

```
class MyFirstStfl extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyFirstStfl({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyFirstStfl> createState() => _MyFirstStflState();
}

class _MyFirstStflState extends State<MyFirstStfl> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 5,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) { 
      return  MySecondStfl(item: index.toString(),);
      },
    );
  }
}

class MySecondStfl extends StatefulWidget {
  final String item;
  const MySecondStfl({Key? key,required this.item}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MySecondStfl> createState() => _MySecondStflState();
}

class _MySecondStflState extends State<MySecondStfl> {
  String myString = '';
  
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    myString = widget.item ; //Here will always and always will take the first item which is '0' asString 
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(myString); // since my Item Count is 5 so it should outputs [0 1 2 3 4] as loop , but it outputs  [0 0 0 0]
  }
}
// Note: that happen only when new data coms from Server , 
// Note: my First Stfl is a screen , the first time  navigate to it so it will outputs correctly [0 1 2 3 4] but if I stay in screen and then new data comes so it always will take the first index
```

in `insitState`  will always and always will take the first item which is `'0'` asString and since my Item Count is 5 so it should outputs `[0 1 2 3 4]` as loop , but it outputs  `[0 0 0 0]`

Note: that happen only when new data comes from server.

Note: my First Stfl is a screen, the first time  navigate to it so it will outputs correctly `[0 1 2 3 4]` but if I stay in screen and then new data comse so it always will take the first index.

But if I put direct the value in text widget so it will always outputs correct result like following

```
Text(widget.item) instead of get it by initstate
```

but this does not fit my case since I need to put value in initstate first then use it in build method

Comment: i think you share wrong link ..

Comment: Yes, sorry. Try to add ValueKey(index) to MySecondStfl. Check line 20 in this example. https://dartpad.dev/?id=22e05de7c38f178f8d782fdfed541685